# Finding the sum $S_n$ of first n terms, check the convergence of the series $\sum_{n=1}^{n-1}(-1)^{n-1}\frac{2n+1}{n(n+1)}$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

Finding the sum $S_n$ of first n terms, check the convergence of the series

$$\sum_{n=1}^{n-1}(-1)^{n-1}\frac{2n+1}{n(n+1)}$$

$u_n=(-1)^{n-1}\frac{2n+1}{n(n+1)}=(-1)^{n-1}[\frac{1}{n}+\frac{1}{n+1}]$

then $S_n=(1/1+1/2)-(1/2+1/3)+(1/3+1/4)...$ terms cancelled out, except the first and last. But last term depends of n=even or odd.

How to show $S_n\to l$, finite number for the convergence of the given series?

Comment: So for $n \ge 2$, you've got $S_n = 1 + (-1)^n \frac{1}{n}$, right?

Comment: $\sum_{n=1}^{n-1}$ this can't be right

Comment: Next time when asking a question, please be more concrete about what the questions is an what you have done. One has to try to guess what is what in this post

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We have

\begin{align}
S_n &= \sum_{i=1}^{n-1}(-1)^{i-1}\frac{2i+1}{i(i+1)}\\
 &= \sum_{i=1}^{n-1}(-1)^{i-1}\left[\frac1i+\frac1{i+1}\right]\\
&= \sum_{i=1}^{n-1} (-1)^{i-1}\frac1i + \sum_{i=1}^{n-1} (-1)^{i-1}\frac1{i+1}\\
&= -\sum_{i=1}^{n-1} \frac{(-1)^{i}}i + \sum_{i=2}^{n} \frac{(-1)^{i}}i\\
&= 1 + \frac{(-1)^{n}}n\\
&\xrightarrow{n\to\infty} 1
\end{align}

Answer (score 2):

You can consider the two cases: 
$$\begin{align}S_{2n-1}=&\sum_{k=1}^{2n-1} (-1)^{k-1}\left[\frac{1}{k}+\frac1{k+1}\right]=\left[1+\frac12\right]-\left[\frac12+\frac13\right]+\cdots +\left[\frac{1}{2n-1}+\frac{1}{2n}\right]=\\
=&1-\frac{1}{2n};\\
S_{2n}=&\sum_{k=1}^{2n} (-1)^{k-1}\left[\frac{1}{k}+\frac1{k+1}\right]=\left[1+\frac12\right]-\left[\frac12+\frac13\right]+\cdots -\left[\frac{1}{2n}+\frac{1}{2n+1}\right]=\\
=&1-\frac{1}{2n+1};\\
\end{align}.$$
Hence:
$$\lim_{n\to\infty} S_{2n-1}=\lim_{n\to\infty}S_{2n}=1.$$